# Beautiful Soup line matching

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

Im trying to build a html table that only contains the table header and the row that is relevant to me. The site I'm using is http://wolk.vlan77.be/~gerben.

I'm trying to get the the table header and my the table entry so I do not have to look each time for my own name.

What I want to do :

- get the html page
- Parse it to get the header of the table
- Parse it to get the line with table tags relevant to me (so the table row containing lucas)
- Build a html page that shows the header and table entry relevant to me

What I am doing now :

- get the header with beautifulsoup first
- get my entry
- add both to an array
- pass this array to a method that generates a string that can be printed as html page

  def downloadURL(self):
          global input
          filehandle = self.urllib.urlopen('http://wolk.vlan77.be/~gerben')
          input = '' 
          for line in filehandle.readlines():
                  input += line
          filehandle.close()

  ```
  def soupParserToTable(self,input):
      global header

      soup = self.BeautifulSoup(input)
      header = soup.first('tr')
      tableInput='0'

      table = soup.findAll('tr')
      for line in table:
          print line
          print '\n \n'
          if '''lucas''' in line:
              print 'true'
          else:
              print 'false'
          print '\n \n **************** \n \n'
  ```

I want to get the line from the html  file that contains lucas, however when I run it like this I get this in my output :

```
 **************** 


<tr><td>lucas.vlan77.be</td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> </tr>



false
```

Now I don't get why it doesn't match, the string lucas is clearly in there :/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're over-complicating this.

Here's a simpler version...

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen('http://wolk.vlan77.be/~gerben')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print soup.find('td', text=lambda data: data.string and 'lucas' in data.string)
lucas.vlan77.be
```

Comment: @LucasKauffman: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? You should put this as a full question, not a comment on an answer.

Comment: TagObject = str(TagObject) fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because line is not a string, but BeautifulSoup.Tag instance. Try to get td value instead:

```
if '''lucas''' in line.td.string:
```

Comment: First line has empty td. Replace with if line.td.string and '''lucas''' in line.td.string: